# Force rerendering Hamburger icon when clicking on button on SideMenu

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When a user click on a page button in the SideMenu, the drawer is closed and the navigation happens.

The HamburgerMenu component has an internal state that contains whether it should be an hamburger sign or an "X".

The problem is that the HamburgerMenu is not aware of this navigation (and thus not aware to the fact that the drawer was closed) so the icon is still "X" when the drawer is closed by the user's click.

I can't find a way to make the SideMenu notify HamburgerMenu about the change/event.

Here is the relevant code from App.js:

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  contentComponent: SideMenu
});

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    DrawerNavigator: {
      screen: DrawerNavigator,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: <HamburgerMenu navigation={navigation} />           
    })
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer;
```

***EDIT:***
Here is my HamburgerMenu code:

```
export default class HamburgerMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            active: false
        }
    }

    onPress(){
        let newActive = !this.state.active;
        this.setState({active: newActive});
        if(newActive){
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
        }
        else {            
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <Hamburger active={this.state.active} type="spinCross" onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)} />
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is no event given for drawer as now but you can make your own by determining Whether drawer is open or close

```
const parent = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
const isDrawerOpen = parent && parent.state && parent.state.isDrawerOpen;
```

so you can maintain the state of the menu click inside the HamburgerMenu

or you can listen to the action from redux as well that is bit complex

Comment: This check will not help because the Hamburger component is not rendered. Where do you suggest i should put it? see Hamburger component code in my post edit